I encountered this error when I was working with shapennet files using the Open3D library
This is the error:

Skipping non-triangle primitive geometry of type: 2

How do I eliminate this error and load the obj file normally?
My Open3D version is 0.14.1.
Code:
cad = o3d.io.read_triangle_mesh(cadroot)
cad = cad.sample_points_uniformly(10000)
cad_homo = np.concatenate((np.array(cad.points), np.ones([np.array(cad.points).shape[0], 1])), axis=-1)


Can you share link to one of the obj file?
